# Pypi: Is it possible to set up git to auto update my package on PyPi?

Tags: python, python-module, pypi

For example if I have a package `foo` that's already on Pypi. I want to be able to `git push origin master` with a new version number in my `setup.py`, and then Pypi somehow auto updates their version/source code. Is this possible? If not is there some similar workflow that someone could share? This is my first time contributing to Pypi and I want to make the experience as easy going as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the behaviour you're after would be best developed using [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). I'm not entirely sure that's the best rabbit hole to go down though, but [here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks) some information if you're interested. (Publishing to Pypi automatically without additional checks could lead to your package being unreliable for other users!)

If you are pushing to PyPI, I assume you are developing an Open Source package? If you are, why not make use of the free CI tool [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to run your tests and other CI tasks. One of your tasks could be to automatically upload your package to [PyPI](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pypi/) on successful new builds.

Comment: Thank you I did not think about my package being unusable if I continuously publish it. But on second thought I'm not going to publish an unstable branch.